# React Native- Error Accessing Fetched JSON data objects

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, networking, javascript-objects

I am very new to React Native, Networking, and Programming as a whole. I am attempting to fetch JSON data from Reddit for an app I'm building, but I am receiving error messages when trying to access the Objects of the data. Below is the code I am using to fetch and console log this data.

```
componentDidMount(){
fetch ('https://www.reddit.com/r/financialindependence.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
       this.setState({
            data: data
    })
  })
  .catch( error => {
      console.error(error)
  })   
}
render() {
    const myData = this.state.data
    if (myData !== undefined) {
        console.log(myData)
}

return(
    <View style = {styles.container}>
        <MainDrawerHeader title = 'Links' />
        <Text> This is the Links Screen </Text>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This works and logs to the console the following.

```
[16:54:41] Object {    
[16:54:41]   "data": Object {
[16:54:41]     "after": "t3_9ysab7",
[16:54:41]     "before": null,
[16:54:41]     "children": Array [
[16:54:41]       Object {
[16:54:41]         "data": Object {
[16:54:41]           "approved_at_utc": null,
[16:54:41]           "approved_by": null,
[16:54:41]           "archived": true,
[16:54:41]           "author": "Omitted For Privacy",
```

And when I access myData.data , it works as well

```
[16:59:29] Object {
[16:59:29]   "after": "t3_9ysab7",
[16:59:29]   "before": null,
[16:59:29]   "children": Array [
[16:59:29]     Object {
[16:59:29]       "data": Object {
[16:59:29]         "approved_at_utc": null,
```

But when I try to access the second nested object (either 'after', 'before', or 'children' (and since children is an array, I tried to access the first element) I receive the following error:

```
[17:00:39] TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: 
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'myData.data.after')
```

Which confuses me because I tried to catch the undefined object with my 'if' statement. **Any tips, not sure where to go from here. Thank you**

Comment: before you call this.setState do a console.log(data) and post here a image of this please.

Comment: Hi Helmer, thanks for responding. Here is the console.log before the setState. (Apologies, I don't know how to format comments): Before Set State:  Object {
[18:13:18]   "data": Object {
[18:13:18]     "after": "t3_9ysab7",
[18:13:18]     "before": null,
[18:13:18]     "children": Array [
[18:13:18]       Object {
[18:13:18]         "data": Object {
[18:13:18]           "approved_at_utc": null,
[18:13:18]           "approved_by": null,
[18:13:18]           "archived": true,

Comment: but i mean a image...

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Hp9GbuD) is the link to the console log. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken here, but in your third line it appears you may not be returning the `res.json()` to the next `.then()` in your Promise chain, like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
   fetch ('https://www.reddit.com/r/financialindependence.json')
   .then(res => { 
       let resultToPass = res.json();
       return resultToPass;
   })
   .then(data => {
     this.setState({
         data: data
     });
   })
   .catch( error => {
   console.error(error)
   })   
}
```

At least superficially that would explain to me why you can access the `res` values and log them but they're not making it to your screen components -- they just aren't making it to where you're calling `this.setState({data: data})`.

Edit: I broke out the return statement by first assigning a variable, but I believe you could just as easily do `return res.json();` and be fine.

Edit 2: Moved the second set of `})` for the `this.setState()` because I made a formatting goof.

Comment: NodeNewb you're a hero! Thank you

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure that's a 100% solution, but I tossed a question out there myself earlier today and figured I'd go for some positive karma and try to help someone else while I await some feedback.

Comment: I spent a solid day troubleshooting something similar recently, so I'm extra happy to help someone else avoid that peril!

Comment: I spent yesterday on this! I'll pay it forward when I can